# Convert expect output from DOS to UNIX style in realtime

Tags: tcl, expect, dos2unix

I write some expect scripts by connecting to a remote host through serial connection.

My problem is that the output of the spawned process (enabled with `log_user 1`) contains DOS-style endings (each line being terminated with `^M` when reading logs in VIM).

I normally run `dos2unix` on all logs at the end of the expect session, to get rid of them. Can the conversion be done in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem is really simple.

What I am doing with my scripts is calling them like below:

```
expect script.exp > mylog
```

As told in the description, `mylog` contains `^M` line-endings when opened in Vim or using `cat -v mylog`.

To get rid of them in real-time, I just call now:

```
expect script.exp | tr -d '\r' > mylog
```