# Copy *unbuffered* stdout to file from within bash script itself

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, named-pipes, tee

I want to copy stdout to a log file from *within* a bash script, meaning I don't want to call the script with output piped to tee, I want the script itself to handle it. I've successfully used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403786/1226020) answer to accomplish this, using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > >(sed "s/^/[${1}] /" | tee -a myscript.log)
exec 2>&1

# <rest of script>
echo "hello"
sleep 10
echo "world"
```

This works, but has the downside of output being buffered until the script is completed, as is also discussed in the linked answer. In the above example, both "hello" and "world" will show up in the log only after the 10 seconds have passed.

I am aware of the stdbuf command, and if running the script with

```
stdbuf -oL ./myscript.sh
```

then stdout is indeed continuously printed both to the file and the terminal.
However, I'd like this to be handled from within the script as well. Is there any way to combine these two solutions? I'd rather not resort to a wrapper script that simply calls the original script enclosed with "stdbuf -oL".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workaround and make the script execute itself with `stdbuf`, if a special argument is present:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" != __BUFFERED__ ]]; then
    prog="$0"
    stdbuf -oL "$prog" __BUFFERED__ "$@"
else
    shift #discard __BUFFERED__

    exec > >(sed "s/^/[${1}] /" | tee -a myscript.log)
    exec 2>&1

    # <rest of script>
    echo "hello"
    sleep 1
    echo "world"
fi
```

This will mostly work:

- if you run the script with `./test`, it shows unbuffered `[] hello\n[] world`.
- if you run the script with `./test 123 456`, it shows `[123] hello\n[123] world` like you want.
- it won't work, however, if you run it with `bash test` - `$0` is set to `test` which is not your script. Fixing this is not in the scope of this question though.

Comment: Thanks. Those limitations are indeed ok. Tbh it's perhaps not the cleanest solution :-) but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

The delay in your first solution is caused by `sed`, not by `tee`. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 6>&1 2>&1>&>(tee -a myscript.log)
```

To "undo" the `tee` effect:

```
exec 1>&6 2>&6 6>&-
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about tee vs sed though? Pretty sure the same thing happened without sed, but I'll double check. Also, would you mind explaining what your suggestion does, what's with the 6?

Comment: I ran into a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786082/convert-expect-output-from-dos-to-unix-style-in-realtime) issue (not fully connected to yours at first sight), in which I was trying to `dos2unix` the output of a certain process by piping its stdout to sed/perl/tr/dos2unix/etc and duplicating it using `tee` simultaneously. I could not get rid of the annoying delay/buffering effect when both enabled. I eventually decided to `tee` *only* and to perform `dos2unix` later. More info on redirecting stdout/stderr to fd6 [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html)

Comment: the `-u, --unbuffered` option on `sed` should, as the `help` says, `load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often`.